# ColdFusion & MongoDB 4 using Java Driver 3.8

Tags: mongodb, coldfusion, mongodb-java

I am trying to perform a wildcard search in Mongo using ColdFusion 11 & The Java MongoDB driver 3.8 on MongoDB 4.0.

The following code gives me errors saying that the method `countDocuments()` cannot be found or the method `find()` cannot be found.

```
<cfset Mongo  = CreateObject("java","com.mongodb.MongoClient").init("localhost")>

<cffunction name="m" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="value" type="any">
    <cfif IsJSON(arguments.value)>
        <cfset local.retrun = CreateObject("java","com.mongodb.util.JSON").parse(arguments.value)>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset local.retrun = CreateObject("java","com.mongodb.util.JSON").parse( SerializeJSON(arguments.value) )>     
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn local.retrun>
</cffunction>

<cfset db = Mongo.getDatabase('fda')>
<cfset DrugInfo = db.getCollection("druginfo")>

<cfset searchCount=druginfo.countDocuments(m({'openfda.brand_name':/Ty/ }))>

<cfset results  = DrugInfo.find(m({'openfda.brand_name': /Ty/})).iterator()>
```

When attempting to do an exact match search, everything works fine.

```
<cfset searchCount=druginfo.countDocuments(m({'openfda.brand_name':'Tylenol'}))>

<cfset results  = DrugInfo.find(m({'openfda.brand_name': 'Tylenol'})).iterator()>
```

I'm basically testing all my queries in Mongo Compass and pasting them into my code but it's not coming working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is not very descriptive.

The Java driver won't take regex'es (or at least not via ColdFusion objects) like Compass does, so you'll have to `$regex` with the pattern between quotes like:

`{ <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }`

---

For example instead of

`m({'openfda.brand_name':/Ty/ })`

use

`m({ 'openfda.brand_name': { '$regex': '^Ty', '$options': 'i' } })`

There is more about how to use `$regex` here:
(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

---

I hope this helps.